# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: reserve - incorrect column/size

Tags: java, pdf, exception

Can someone explain what is a reason of this exception?

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: reserve - incorrect column/size
>     at com.lowagie.text.Row.reserve(Row.java:272)   at
>   com.lowagie.text.Row.addElement(Row.java:225)     at
>   com.lowagie.text.Table.placeCell(Table.java:1567)     at
>   com.lowagie.text.Table.addCell(Table.java:577)    at
>   com.lowagie.text.Table.addCell(Table.java:590)

I can't find clear explanation on google.

```
_tmp = new Cell(new Phrase(sm.getString("xxx"), font));
_tmp.setHorizontalAlignment(Cell.ALIGN_RIGHT);
_tmp.setColspan(3);
_tmp.setBorderWidthBottom(0);
_tmp.setBorderWidthLeft(0);
table.addCell(_tmp);
```

Comment: Show us the code that triggers this.

Comment: Can you include some of your code?

Comment: try increasing setColspan to a bigger number.

Comment: An `IndexOutOfBounds` exception occurs when you try to access an element that doesn't exist in the array. For example, if you have an array that contains 5 elements, and you try accessing the sixth element, you would get an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception. Try to debug your code with this in mind. Have a look at the `Row` class. The stack trace mentions that the flow started in that class at line 272.